# Clang optimization: && vs &: optimized vs. non-optimized (for certain values)

Tags: c, optimization, x86, clang, bitwise-operators

`clang -O3` optimizes this code:

```
_Bool f1(char x)
{
    _Bool b1 = x == 4;
    _Bool b2 = x & 3;
    return b1 & b2;
}
```

to:

```
f1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

However, `clang -O3` does not optimize this code:

```
_Bool f1(char x)
{
    _Bool b1 = x == 2;
    _Bool b2 = x & 1;
    return b1 & b2;
}
```

```
f1:
        cmp     dil, 2
        sete    al
        and     al, dil
        ret
```

Why?

Note: the `&` `b1 & b2` is used intentionally. If `&&` is used, then `clang -O3` optimizes it to:

```
f1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

How it can be explained?

Comment: A missed optimization?

Comment: gcc optimizes neither of them.

Comment: Also if you include caller code both clang and gcc seem to replace the function call with `xor     eax, eax` even though they failed to optimize the functions stand-alone. This is weird. https://godbolt.org/z/1qGsrrb3P

Comment: @Lundin, Not weird. Resolving an equation for a known input is a completely different problem than simplifying an equation with variables, and it's a trivial problem to solve. While simplifying an equation with variables is anything but simple.

Comment: @ikegami But it omits the function calls no matter which value you pass, as it ought to. So the compiler(s) have made the conclusion that the functions can never return anything but zero yet didn't optimize the actual functions.

Comment: Re "*the compiler(s) have made the conclusion that the functions can never return anything but zero*", No. the compiler(s) have made the conclusion that `f1` can never return anything but zero **for x=4**. Same for `f2` and `x=2`. Like I said in my earlier comment, that's a completely different problem than "never return anything but zero **for any x**"

Comment: @ikegami So how to explain this? https://godbolt.org/z/j8YWeM47b. Here I test the functions with all possible values a `char` can have. Some inlined code is generated. Then enable `#define LOGIC_AND` and suddenly the whole program transfers into a no-op. (gcc fails to optimize either way)

Comment: @Lundin, That is weird.

Comment: @Lundin Re: GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106138. Re: "no-op": impressive.

Comment: @pmor: Thanks for reporting it as a GCC missed-optimization bug, but GCC bug reports should have very specific titles ("summary" in the submit UI).  There are very many different ways that code could possibly end up with a compile time constant return value; your case is specific to logical or bitwise AND of booleanized compare and AND results.  If you can edit the title of your own bug report, I'd suggest "AND of disjoint booleans from compare and bitwise not optimized to constant false".

Comment: Also not a bad idea to include a Godbolt shortlink (perhaps in the comment that goes with a title edit on bugzilla), like Lundin's MCVE with LOGICAL_AND as an option: https://godbolt.org/z/qvosv8q7c with `static` removed from the separate functions, showing GCC trunk (13), as well as clang doing the optimization.  Also, GCC devs generally prefer AT&T syntax for x86 bug reports (unfortunately), so I used that on Godbolt.

Comment: If you also want to report for clang, they recently moved to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues for issue-tracking.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. 1) Edited. 2) Created https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56294.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

[Inefficient code generation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56294) (due to "missing narrowing transforms for bitwise logic").